# Suspensão de publicação de aplicativo na Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Meu aplicativo foi suspenso após uma tentativa de publicação em ambiente alpha de teste aberto.

Pergunta: existe alguma maneira de submeter o aplicativo e o mesmo for avaliado sem gerar impacto para conta de desenvolvedor?

Sou realmente amador nessa área e tenho poucos dias de experiência com a Google Play. Pesquisei bastante antes de fazer a submissão para justamente evitar esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Alpha e teste aberto? O nome comum que se dá ao teste aberto é beta, normalmente se mantendo o alpha reservado para teste fechado. Claro, essa nomenclatura é uma convenção fraca, ninguém é obrigado a seguir, mas esses são os padrões mais comuns de mercado

Comment: O que é meio confuso no painel do Google Play. No meu entendimento o Alpha não estaria sujeito a qualquer tipo de sanção em caso de ferimento das diretrizes e há a possiblidade de deixá-lo como teste aberto.

A minha ideia é somente não causar outro strike na minha conta por falta de experiência.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim Allysson, você pode publicar na Alpha e deixar aberto apenas para sua lista de testadores. Na própria página de controle da versão você pode fazer isso. O controle de testadores é feito através do e-mail cadastrado na Google play. Após cadastrar alguém na lista de testadores envie o link de testador para a pessoa acessar e aceitar ser um testador.

Edit:
O local exato pra fazer isso no console é em "Gerenciar versões" > Gerenciar Alpha, selecione "teste Alpha fechado" e cadastre seus testadores. Aparecerá o link de ativação que o testador deverá acessar pra aceitar ser um testador.

Comment: Renan, obrigado pela resposta. Vou tentar novamente, mas dessa vez submetendo o aplicativo em teste fechado para previnir outro strike.